Reduce memory use for Breadth-First Search
I am a novice to Comp Science topics. I have been struggling with reducing the memory use when performing a breadth-first search.
For demonstration:
Given a Directed Acyclical Graph (DAG) from Cormen et al. Find all unique paths from source (1) to sink (6).
vertices: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
edges: [(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 4), (3, 2), (3, 5), (4, 6), (5, 4), (5, 6)]
Same information as an adjacency map (python dictionary):
adj = {1:\[2, 3\], 2:\[4\], 3:\[2, 5\], 4:\[6\], 5:\[4, 6\]}

In the code below, I save path as a list of edges.
There are two things in the queue: the next edge to add to path, and the path so far.
As the number of edges become 1800 or so, the memory requirement of this code becomes more than 500 MB. Queue has the largest memory use.
Is there a way to do BFS with much lesser memory use?
def BFS(adj):
    all_paths = []
    for v in adj[1]:
        queue = deque()
        queue.append(((1, v),[]))
        while queue:
            (w, x), path = queue.pop()
            path.append((w, x))
            if x not in adj.keys():
                continue
            for y in adj[x]:
                if y == n: # reached sink
                    # convert list of edges to final - a list of vertices
                    path.append((x, y))
                    a = path[0][0]
                    final = [a]
                    for e in path:
                        final.append(e[1])
                    if final not in all_paths:
                        all_paths.append(final)
                    continue
                elif (x, y) not in path:
                    tmp = [i for i in path]
                    queue.appendleft(((x,y), tmp))
                    
    return all_paths

The expected output:
[[1, 2, 4, 6], [1, 3, 5, 6], [1, 3, 2, 4, 6], [1, 3, 5, 4, 6]]


What's the correct output for the given input in the question?

I have edited the question to reflect the correct output

The size of the output can be exponential in the size of the input, so there isn't actually a whole lot of room to optimize the memory consumption, if you really need this output in this form. Is "produce this output in this specific form" the underlying goal here, or do you want to do something with the output? If you want to do something with the output, you can likely find a better way to do it.

BFS is the wrong algorithm if you want to save on memory. Why not DFS?

Thank you @user2357112

Thank you @trincot. I am doing this problem as a challenge for a course where the two limitations are time and memory. DFS saves on memory, but takes much longer.

"DFS ... takes much longer": that is not my experience. I actually expect DFS to be at least as fast if not faster. You may want to look at your DFS implementation again.

You could use set(), tuple() and generators:
from collections import deque

def BFS(adj, n):
    all_paths = set()
    for v in adj[1]:
        queue = deque()
        queue.append((1, v, [(1, v)]))

        while queue:
            w, x, path = queue.pop()
            if x == n:
                all_paths.add(tuple([1] + [p[1] for p in path]))
                continue

            if x in adj:
                for y in adj[x]:
                    if y != w:
                        queue.appendleft((x, y, path + [(x, y)]))

    return (tuple(path) for path in all_paths)


print(list(BFS({1: [2, 3], 2: [4], 3: [2, 5], 4: [6], 5: [4, 6]}, 6)))


Output:
[(1, 3, 2, 4, 6), (1, 3, 5, 4, 6), (1, 2, 4, 6), (1, 3, 5, 6)]


Check and see if the algorithm output is correct.


please add more detail why @user13232362 should use set , tuple instead of list and how this code makes low memory use

See here for further details.

Thanks @123 This will sure save memory on the margins. I was wondering if there is a drastically different way of thinking about the problem, where I may not have to save the large and bulky queue. So far I have not been able to get at one; and there may not be one at all.

It's not actually possible to get duplicate paths, so the set doesn't help. Also, the if y != w test is unnecessary, since the input is a directed acyclic graph, and y == w would imply a directed cycle.
